# matlab - too many loops finding paths array from Adjacency

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

Like the title says I would like to make the code faster and easier to read.

I have an Adjacency matrix:

```
Ad=[  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0;
      1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1;
      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0];
```

and a `Name={'a';'b';'c';'d';'E';'F';'a';'E';'d';'F'};` that I will use for describing a type of "planet".

After finding out some new words from past comments from deleted questions, I could come up with a start:

```
dig=digraph(Ad, Name);
[Num.Nodes,Num.Null]=size(dig.Nodes);
for j2=1:Num.Nodes
 dfs{j2}=dfsearch(dig,(j2),'allevents');
 Num.node2path=dfs{j2}.Node;
 Num.tokeep = ~isnan(Num.node2path);
 Num.node2path = Num.node2path(Num.tokeep);
 Num.node2path(1)=[];
 [Num.node2path2,Num.Null]=size(Num.node2path);
  for i2=1:Num.node2path2-1
   if Num.node2path(i2)==Num.node2path(i2+1)
   path{j2,i2}=Num.node2path(1:i2);Num.node2path(i2)=1000;Num.node2path(i2+1)=1001;
    if Num.node2path(i2-1)==Num.node2path(i2+2)
    Num.node2path(i2-1)=1002;Num.node2path(i2+2)=1003;
    end
   end
  end
 end
path = path(~cellfun('isempty',path));
[Num.clear1000,Num.degeaba] = size(path);
for i3=1:Num.clear1000
 Num.is1000 = find(path{i3}(:) == 1000);
 path{i3}(Num.is1000)=[];
 Num.is1000 = find(path{i3}(:) == 1001);
 path{i3}(Num.is1000)=[];
 Num.is1000 = find(path{i3}(:) == 1002);
 path{i3}(Num.is1000)=[];
 Num.is1000 = find(path{i3}(:) == 1003);
 path{i3}(Num.is1000)=[];
 end
```

The thing is I feel it is getting too complicated with too many loops and I haven't even got to having the result I wanted. For example the path between '2' and '6' would be `[2;1;5;3;4;6]` and could be found with some more loops looking for `path{i4}(1);` equal to 2 and `path{i4}(end);` equal to 6, i4 being 10.

So after finding all paths I would like to rename the paths using `Name`, since I assign the same name to the same kind of "planet". Next I will choose the shortest path to the "best planet".

The paths being now in the form of `[a;E;d]` are compared to paths of `Ad2` and `Name2`. Paths with the same Name are going to be saved and compared if they have similar distances from the first "planet" to the last one, just like the one that started the search. I quote "planets" because they may be stars, asteroids, and even these are categorized so this is where `Name` is coming from.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find the shortest path through the points? The length of all paths between points? The minimum spanning tree? Please explain.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I am looking for similar path to follow to reach some "planets", will add some more details now

Comment: That didn't really help. You don't say what type of paths you're looking for. And now there are apparently some "planets"? What are those and how do you choose the "best planet"? Any problem description that degenerates to "bla bla" is probably unanswerable.

Comment: sorry will try to get it better